# React - Mapping Inherited Props onto HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs

I think the code is quite self explanatory. I want to map `this.props.tabAttr` (an array of objects) on to HTML elements.

```
import React from 'react';
var Tab = React.createClass ({

        propTypes : {
            tabAttr : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
        },

        render : function () {
            return (
                {this.props.tabAttr.map (function (ob) {
                    return (
                        <div class = {ob.tabClassName}>
                            <span> {ob.tabName} </span>
                        </div>
                    )}
                )}
            );
        }
    });

    export default Tab;
```

Webpack is reporting an error on `{this.props.tabAttr.map (function (ob) {...`
: Module build failed, unexpected token...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React for set `class` attribute you should use `className` instead of `class`, change this

```
 <div class = {ob.tabClassName}>
```

to

```
 <div className={ob.tabClassName}>
```

and component **must have** only one root element

```
render: function () {
  var tabs = this.props.tabAttr.map (function (ob, index) {
    return <div key={index} className={ob.tabClassName}>
      <span> {ob.tabName} </span>
    </div>
  });

  // Component has only one root element
  return <div>
    { tabs }
  </div>;
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26039/)